# Chervolet 2008 Suburban, how to remove transmission fluid pan? Cable mount is in the way

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, transmission-fluid

Was trying to follow [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mRGHERUytKE&t=79s) for a transmission fluid change (even though his is a 2007 and mine is a 2008), but at the marked point, he says to pry a certain cable mount out of the way, and for my vehicle this does not seem plausible. I've pried it as far as I dare, and the pan still can't get loose. Still, he doesn't actually show the prying, so maybe I'm doing something wrong? Is this cable mount easy to remove and put back?

Update: My dad was able to get the linkage out of the way with a C clamp, but that seems a far cry from a flat head screwdriver, so I’d be glad to hear of a better way. Will leave the question open for now.

Comment: If the transmission pan looks the same, it's probably the same thing. There were three different engines you could get in the Suburban. If your 'Burban is a different model (1500 v 2500), it could have a different transmission in it then what they are showing in the video. I believe with the 5.3L it had a 4L60e. If it has a 6.0L or 6.2L it would have a 4L80e. This might be why it seems different. I've not taken the pan off of one before, so couldn't tell you for sure how to get it past the linkage *for sure*, but would bet you can disconnect it at the transmission and move it out of the way.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I might do that next time, but I am concerned that the cable is under tension, and it would be really hard to put back.

Comment: It's not under tension. It is the shift linkage. If it were under tension it would be shifting it without your help.